# How can I fix duplicate dependency in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to compile and build my project, but whenever I build my project I get duplicate errors and it always come when I add firebase dependency to my project I solved the first one by researching online and I added this implementation `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'` to fix the conflict, now i added a new firebase dependency which is  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0''`I am still unable to build my app

Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.2)
D

below is my build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sckoolboy.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 20210420
        versionName '5.1.1'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'

    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:6.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
    implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bhargavms:DotLoader:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.codemybrainsout:smart-app-rate:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.gauravk.bubblenavigation:bubblenavigation:1.0.7'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
    implementation  files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please what am I doing wrong? 1 million thanks as you help me on this.

Comment: Hi Osas Divine , I have added one answer to your question . If it is something you were looking for , please mark it as right answer so other can refer it . If it is not working in your case you can comment below the answer !

Answer (score 0):

please check your `dependencies`  :

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.8'

    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'

    // ...
}
```

remove the duplicate,

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'
```

helps

Comment: I didn't notice this duplicate, pretty quick. Phew!!! Plenty thanks

Comment: Do accept the answer if you found the solution to encourage people in stack overflle help more user like you

Answer (score 0):

You have added Exoplayer dependency 2 times with a different version.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.2'
```

Check your Gradle file and remove the duplicate one.

Answer (score 0):

When you add **write something into code which can be optimized or not required** , Android  Studio has feature to **highlight** that thing.Now in this case if you have **added unused , duplicate or not required dependencies** , Android Studio will **highlight** them as **below** !

[image]

Hovering mouse on the **yellow highlighted lines** , some **suggestions** may appear by Android Studio as below !

[image]

You can **remove duplicate dependencies** by removing them as above shown image and that will **optimize** your project as well !